# TypeError: train_test_split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scoring'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sklearn

После замены `train_test_split.cross_val_score` на `train_test_split` перестало работать:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsOneClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from matplotlib import pyplot
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Input file containing data
input_file = 'income_data.txt'

# Read the data
X = []
y = []
count_class1 = 0
count_class2 = 0
max_datapoints = 25000

with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if count_class1 >= max_datapoints and count_class2 >= max_datapoints:
            break

        if '?' in line:
            continue

        data = line[:-1].split(', ')

        if data[-1] == '<=50K' and count_class1 < max_datapoints:
            X.append(data)
            count_class1 += 1

        if data[-1] == '>50K' and count_class2 < max_datapoints:
            X.append(data)
            count_class2 += 1

# Convert to numpy array
X = np.array(X)

# Convert string data to numerical data
label_encoder = [] 
X_encoded = np.empty(X.shape)
for i,item in enumerate(X[0]):
    if item.isdigit(): 
        X_encoded[:, i] = X[:, i]
    else:
        label_encoder.append(preprocessing.LabelEncoder())
        X_encoded[:, i] = label_encoder[-1].fit_transform(X[:, i])

X = X_encoded[:, :-1].astype(int)
y = X_encoded[:, -1].astype(int)

# Create SVM classifier
classifier = OneVsOneClassifier(LinearSVC(random_state=0))

# Train the classifier
classifier.fit(X, y)

# Cross validation
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=5)
classifier = OneVsOneClassifier(LinearSVC(random_state=0))
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_test_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Compute the F1 score of the SVM classifier
f1 = cross_validation.cross_val_score(classifier, X, y, scoring='f1_weighted', cv=3)
print("F1 score: " + str(round(100*f1.mean(), 2)) + "%")

# Predict output for a test datapoint
input_data = ['37', 'Private', '215646', 'HS-grad', '9', 'Never-married', 'Handlers-cleaners', 'Not-in-family', 'White', 'Male', '0', '0', '40', 'United-States']

# Encode test datapoint
input_data_encoded = [-1] * len(input_data)
count = 0
for i, item in enumerate(input_data):
    if item.isdigit():
        input_data_encoded[i] = int(input_data[i])
    else:
        input_data_encoded[i] = int(label_encoder[count].transform(input_data[i]))
        count += 1 

input_data_encoded = np.array(input_data_encoded)

# Run classifier on encoded datapoint and print output
predicted_class = classifier.predict(input_data_encoded)
print(label_encoder[-1].inverse_transform(predicted_class)[0])
```

Проблемы с `cross_validation`:

```py
# Cross validation
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=5)
classifier = OneVsOneClassifier(LinearSVC(random_state=0))
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_test_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Compute the F1 score of the SVM classifier
f1 = cross_validation.cross_val_score(classifier, X, y, scoring='f1_weighted', cv=3)
print("F1 score: " + str(round(100*f1.mean(), 2)
) + "%")
```

Comment: Не вижу в документации метода такого аргумента (вы и сами могли это сделать :) ): https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn-model-selection-train-test-split. Посмотрел описание cross_val_score https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html и не понимаю смысла менять одну функцию на другую - у них разный смысл

Comment: @gil9red из-за новой версии scikit-learn: scikit-learn v0.20.0

Comment: Unresolved reference 'cross_validation' отказывается работать

Comment: Текущая версия scikit-learn 1.2.0. Нужно смотреть на что в новой версии поменяли cross_validation. Да и вопрос легко гуглится. Вот с cross_validation решение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844352/5909792

Comment: Реально какая-то странная у вас замена. Насколько я понимаю, в `Sklearn` функции просто периодически переезжают в другой подмодуль, но сами функции остаются обычно теми же самыми. А вы зачем-то поменяли не модуль, из которого импортируется функция, а саму функцию. Теперь у вас одна и та же функция используется для абсолютно разных целей. Это выглядит явно неправильным. Кстати, если бы вы добавили в код все относящиеся к вашему фрагменту кода `import`-ы, то было бы гораздо проще разобраться, в чём проблема.

Comment: @gil9red добавил весь код и import

Comment: Импорты у вас правильные. Вы пробовали просто без префикса `cross_validation.` использовать `train_test_split` и `cross_val_score`?

Answer (score 2):

У вас совершенно правильные импорты:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

И вызывать эти функции нужно просто по именам, без префикса `cross_validation.`:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=5)
...
f1 = cross_val_score(classifier, X, y, scoring='f1_weighted', cv=3)
```

И это разные функции, нельзя одну из них использовать вместо другой. Вы просто запутались в названиях модулей библиотеки `sklearn` и названиях функций. Эти функции в одной из версий переехали из одного модуля в другой, но сами названия функций и их назначение остались прежними. Всё, что нужно было исходно - это поменять импорт, сам код менять не нужно было бы, если бы он изначально не был привязан к названию модулей.